# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager has not been bound (Using JakeWharton ViewPager Indicator)

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I have two view pagers in a screen.One ViewPager uses JakeWharton' circleindicator and second one uses TabPage Indicator. I need to download the data from backend using Async call.Once the data is download i should be displaying the data in the viewpagers.
Here is the Code snippet of my activity.

```
   ViewPager pager1;
ViewPager pager2;

public onCreate(){
     //I Set Up ContentView
     //Locate ViewPagers & Indicators
     //pager1 = ...
     //pager2= ...
     //Locate Indicators
     CallAsyncTask().execute();


}
private class CallAsyncTask extends AsynTask{
          doinbackground(){
          //Download Data
          }
          onPostExecute(){
            displayData();

          }

}
private displayData(){
   // Set Up Adapters & Indicators for ViewPagers
}
```

when i execute this code, i get **ViewPager Not Bound Exception**.
Is there a solution for it. I think  **a workaround is to setUpContentView inside onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask.But i also need to display progressBars till the data is downloaded**. How can i achieve all of this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868885/viewpager-has-not-been-bound

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just placed `visibility: gone` on the `TabPageIndicator` and when I get the data to display I change the visibility to visible

Comment: yes. the method that was throwing the exception was called onLayout or onMeasure. that's why I set the visibility: gone until I set up the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

In my case what i found is that i am not setting the "ViewPager" to  "TabPageIndicator". After setting

```
indicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

my issue is gone.